# Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 2 new Device Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-emulator, android-studio-bumblebee

Hey guys I just updated Android Studio, I am glad that they finally fixed the bug where you could not open up the Device Manager. However they changed the look of it and it now comes inside AS or as a much much larger window (see my screenshot).

[image]

Is there a way to make it look like it was before? So just the Device with its frame and not that huge window around it? Also Crtl+M doesnt work and Crtl+Upkey/Downkey do not change the size of the emulator like it used to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to Preferences of Android Studio
2. Search for emulator, or navigate to tools -> Emulator
3. Uncheck the Launch in a tool window

Comment: Yeah that solves it, thanks!